# Dell Precision 7530 touch screen laptop randomly fires MS-Windows events. System becomes unusable

Tags: laptop, mouse, dell-precision

I have a Dell Precision 7530 laptop with a touch-screen running Windows 10.  I use an external Dell WD15 Docking Station with 2 external monitors, USB keyboard and mouse, so I can close the laptop lid.

After some time working with the lid closed, the system starts randomly firing MS-Windows events like I am moving the mouse cursor and right-clicking in random locations.

- Menus pop up in random locations Notification windows starting
  flashing.
- File Explorer and minimized apps the Task Bar start to open and close.
- Windows Start Key and Start Menu opens and closes.
- Application windows get minimized and maximized without notice.

The system becomes completely unusable, operating like gremlins are using another mouse and keyboard, opening and closing things randomly.

I try disconnecting and/or rebooting the docking station.  As a last resort, I reboot the computer.  That seems to help for a while, but not always or not for long.  I've called Dell support several times, and gone through BIOS upgrades for the Docking Station and the Precision laptop.

I've replaced the mouse several times and tried with different mice from Dell, Lenovo, and other generic ones.

I've upgraded BIOS and drivers for the system and docking station about 5 times on my own, and the problem still occurs.

The WD15 docking station uses a USB-C cable sticking straight out of the left side of the laptop.  I HATE this location; it should be in the back.  (Whoever made that design decision should be fired for usability ignorance.)  I thought it was a faulty WD15, cable, or connector, but all parts check fine on another computer.

Is anyone else experiencing this random firing of window events in Windows 10 ?

If yes, what fixes are there?

Dell does not have a permanent fix for it.

##################################################

In a long discussion with a Dell Tech Support Staffer, we discovered a source of the problem, but not a good solution.

The problem starts only after the touch screen heats up with the lid closed.  After operating for a while, static electricity seems to build up inside the closed lid.  Inside the close lid, the touch screen has micro-discharges of static buildup that make it appear like someone is randomly touching the screen.  The longer the system is on, the more static buildup that occurs and the worse the random window events get.

One workaround is to open the screen and leave it open for a while.  Eventually the random firing events stop -- after the static dissipates or the screen cools down.  Opening the lid when this happens is a bad solution because I need the space on my desktop, and it disrupts my work.  I want to keep the lid closed and use the 2 external monitors.

Another workaround is to disable the touch-screen capabilities.  This stops the touch screen static charge buildup and the random events.  Here is a link that explains how to disable / enable the touchscreen feature.  [Enable and disable your touchscreen in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028019/windows-enable-and-disable-your-touchscreen-in-windows-10)

However, disabling the touch screen is not an optimal solution.  Occasionally I remove the laptop from the docking station to use it stand-alone.  But then I cannot use the touchscreen until I re-enable it.  A bit of a hassle.

Does anyone know if there's a chemical solution, surfactant, or some other physical method to dissipate these charges automatically?